# Исключить определённые ID из SQL-запроса

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT id_post 
  FROM kubx_post_order 
 WHERE type='people_about' 
   AND NOT id_post='1622,1623' 
 LIMIT 6;
```

Мне нужно вывести список `ID`, но исключить из результата определённые значения поля `id_post`. Как написать корректный запрос? Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT id_post 
  FROM kubx_post_order 
 WHERE type='people_about' 
   AND id_post NOT IN  (1622, 1623)
 LIMIT 6;
```

Используйте конструкцию `NOT IN` для исключения ненужных результатов. В скобках так же можно написать подзапрос